# Python: Average a list and append to dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I have a dictionary of names with a number (a score) assigned to them. The file is laid out as so:

```
Person A,7
Peron B,6
```

If a name is repeated in the file e.g. Person B occurred on 3 lines with 3 different scores I want to calculate the mean average of these scores then append this result to a dictionary in the form of a list. However, I keep encountering an error when i try to sort the dictionary. Code below.

```
else:
for key in results:
    keyValue = results[key]
    if len(keyValue) > 1:
        # Line below this needs modification
        keyValue = list(sum(keyValue)/len(keyValue))
        newResults[key] = keyValue
        # Error in above code...
    else:
        newResults[key] = keyValue
print(newResults)
print(sorted(zip(newResults.values(), newResults.keys()), reverse=True))
```

Results is a dictionary of the people (the keys) and their scores (the values) where the values are lists so that:

```
results = {'Bob':[7],'Jane':[8,9]}
```

Comment: which version of python are you using? 3.x or 2.7?

Comment: I am using version 3.3

Comment: so instead of appending a raw value to the list assigned to person, you want to append current mean? for example having value of `4` and current list `[1, 2, 3]` eventually you want to have `[1, 2, 3, 2.5]`?

Comment: So in the end instead of having for example 'Jane':[7,8,9] in the results dictionary I want to have 'Jane':[8] (as 8 is the mean of 7,8 and 9) in the newResults dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.x you can use its `statistics` library which contains a function `mean`. Now assuming that your dict looks like: `results = {'Bob': [7], 'Jane': [8, 9]}` you can create a `newResults` dict like this:

```
from statistics import mean
newResults = {key: mean(results[key]) for key in results}
```

This is called dict comprehension and as you can see it's kinda intuitive. Starting with `{` you're telling that dict is going to be created. Then with `key: value` you're defining its structure. Lastly, with `for` loop you iterate over a collection that will be used for the dict creation. You can achieve the same with:

```
newResults = {}
for key in results:
    newResults[key] = mean(results[key])
```

You want to sort the dict in the end. Unfortunately it's not possible. You can either create an `OrderedDict`, which remembers the items insertion order or a list which will contain sorted keys to your dict. The latter will look like:

```
sortedKeys = sorted(newResults, key=lambda x: newResults[x])
```